# sequelize connection timeout with cloud sql proxy in node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

Running a local config, the connection works fine. I've installed and have a cloud_sql_proxy running and ready for new connections.

Here's my sequelize connection code:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS, {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  host: `/cloudsql/${CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME}`,
  pool: {
        max: 30,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000,
        acquire: 1000000,
      },
  dialectOptions: {
    connectTimeout: 100000
  }
});
```

At some point I set my max connection, acquire, and connectTimeout variables to absurdly high numbers, but still no luck, but I started getting a specific IP address located in London on port 3306.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? Can you share more specific info or even logs ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to the cloud db by modifying my config to the following:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS, {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  host: DB_HOST,
  timestamps: false,
  pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
      },
});
```

The difference is I pointed the host to the actual db IP address instead of the `/cloudsql/${CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME}` path.